# Solving the integral $\int \sqrt{C^2 - \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $C$ be a real constant, $C\neq0$. I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$
\int \sqrt{C^2 - \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}dx
$$
If $C = \pm 1$, I known how to solve it (by using the substitution x=sinh(u)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It leads to an Elliptic one $$-\frac{i \sqrt{x^2+1} \sqrt{C^2-\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}}
   E\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}(x)|1-\frac{1}{C^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(1-\frac
   {1}{C^2}\right) x^2+1}}$$

Comment: This somewhat simplifies to $$-i|C|E\left(i \text{arsinh}(x)\,\Bigg|\,1 - \frac1{c^2}\right)$$for real $x,C$.

Answer (score -1):

Use the substitution $x = \tan \theta$ which after differentiating becomes $ \mathrm{d}x = \sec\theta \mathrm{d}\theta $. The integral now becomes:
$$ \int\sqrt{ C^2 - \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}}\mathrm{d}x = \int \sqrt{C^2 - \frac{\tan^2\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta}}\sec\theta \mathrm{d}\theta = \int\frac{\sqrt{C^2-\sin^2\theta}}{\cos\theta} \mathrm{d}\theta$$
This form of the integral can be now solved but comming to the solution is rather tideous so here is a link of a site https://www.integral-calculator.com/ which will solve this integral in a step-by-step solution with only elementary functions in the final solution. If I manage to find a nicer solution I will post it.

Comment: Why the downvote :'( ?